# HTML Input has focus, but I can't edit it after using .val()

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input

So here is the problem.
I have `facebook` page tab app. In it there is a `form` with text inputs and a button "`Facebook login`".
When the user clicks the button `jQuery` fills in the form with user data received from Facebook Graph. Form is managed with JS `Formly` and `jQuery`.
So if the user fills the info manually there is no problem, but if he uses "`Facebook Login`" he can't edit inputs until iframe losses focus and then gain it again.
The problem only persists in **Firefox**, **Chrome** and **IE works like a charm**.

```
    function login(vpis) {
        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                    console.log("Welcome! Fetching your information.... ");
                    FB.api("/me", function(response) {
                        if(vpis)
                        {
                            $("#mail")[0].value = response.email;
                            $("#mail2")[0].value = response.email;
                            $("#Name")[0].value = response.first_name;
                            $("#Surname")[0].value = response.last_name;
                            $("#BirthYear")[0].value = response.birthday.substring(6);
                            //blur();
                            myWindow=window.open("","","width=10,height=10");
                            myWindow.close();
                            //$("#tel").focus();
                        }
            } else {
                    console.log("User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.");
            }
        }, {scope: "email,user_birthday,user_likes"});
}
```

---

Link to Formly.js http://fb.3art.si/rubrike/js/formly.js

Here is the function where I fill in the form. I tried to use a lame tweak, to lose focus, but there is a problem when Firefox blocks it.

---

Any help is highly apriciated, and sorry for my bad english. I have scaned the google for answer, but could not find it...

Comment: Oh i forgot to attach link to app [link](https://www.facebook.com/rubrike.net/app_456411711111066)